# Schengen Tourist Visa (Multi)

Tags: schengen, europe, tourist-visas

I have a tourist multi entry C visa (Etats Schengen) from the Swiss consulate in the U.S and was wondering the following below:

1) Can I travel to other Schengen countries without any issues given I have 
   obtained the tourist visa from Swiss consulate.

2) Do I have to enter Switzerland since my tourist visa was provided by the 
   Swiss consulate and then book my flight/train to other Schengen 
   countries?

3) Can I fly into another Schengen country without having to fly into 
   Switzerland?

4) Do I have to fly out of Switzerland to come back home to the U.S since 
   the tourist visa was provided to me by the Swiss consulate or can I fly 
   out from another Schengen country back home to the U.S?

Please provide me some form of assistance as I need to book my trip itinerary accordingly and as soon as possible.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes No Yes No respectively

Comment: Thank you so much @user56513
Your quick response is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Remember that the **first** use of a multi visa should be in accordance with the itinerary/premise of the trip you gave in the application. Minor changes are possible, this includes such things as entering Schengen in a different airport to catch a more convenient flight, but somebody who looks at your plans should think "yep, that's still the original purpose."

Comment: You apply your visa at the consulate of the county of the **major** portion of your planed trip. Sample: enter in Vienna, take train to Switzerland and stay for a week. Take a train to Paris and fly out.